# How to set the cover-image property in a epub file

Tags: python, image, epub, epub3, calibre

I created some e-books in `epub` (using Python) with a cover page and cover image.
The e-books work fine, except for one thing: the cover image does not show in the file icon/tile on my MacBook and Kindle.
Using `Calibre`, I can mark the image I use for the cover as `cover image`. Then the cover shows on my MacBook as well as on my Kindle.

Is there a way to set this property manually in the epub?

In Python, I created all the chapter files and other required files, zipped the folder and changed the `.zip` extension to `.epub`. After setting the cover image in `Calibre`, it is no longer possible to unzip the `.epub` to see what has changed.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?
https://www.w3.org/TR/epub-33/#sec-cover-image